# JetBrains Rider IDE - Is debugging .Net Core 1.1.X possible?

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1, rider

I am currently developing an API using .NET Core 1.1.1 using the JetBrains Rider 2017.1 IDE.
When trying to run the program, I encounter the following error:

"*Failed to start debugging session. Try installing .NET Core SDK 1.0.4 or a later stable 1.0.x release* "

Is debugging using Rider possible on .NET Core 1.1.X? And if so how can I make it happen ?

Comment: Did you even install the SDK tools in question, whether it be 1.0.x or 1.1.x?

Comment: I just re-installed de SDK tools for both version and tested for both. The result is the same as before. @Tseng

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I successfully debugged a .NET Core 1.1 app with JetBrains Rider 2017.2 and 2017.3.

But I encountered the **same issue** today as you: a message popped up saying "failed to start debugging session".

I found that this was because **my solution configuration was broken**. I accidentally left an empty line in the environment variables editor of the configuration editor. Debugger failed to start on any configuration. Run was fine.

I deleted the empty line, saved configuration, launched again the debugger and everything works now as before.

Rider log file (Help > Show Log in Explorer) said only a warning:

> WARN | GeneralCommandLine | Skipping environment variable with empty name, value:

I think JetBrains should treat that as an error instead of a warning ...

Comment: Thanks for this, never would have found that on my own. Do you know if this has been reported to JetBrains? Definitely needs a better user experience.